# spring boot custom rolling log file

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, logging

We have a spring boot application, and use logback with rolling files to create json and standard log files.

We use filebeat to scrape the log.json files and push to the elk server

I would like to add an  op.json  custom json rolling log file in the log directory.   This is to collect information on operations called and perf info.

Basily, I just want to  use a class that manage rolling files.    In the class, there will be a logOp function that accects a java object, and serializes it, added some standard log fields to the json output.

Questions:
1) {Not linkly, but would be nice} is there functionality in logback that will allow me to created a named logger that will append a string (serialized JSON in my case) to the end of op.json log file, and implement rolling logger functionality

2) if this is not available through logback (which I would understand).  Is there a java package that manages appending a string to a rolling file?   I could just create an instance of this "Appender" and add strings to it.   This would be like a standanone Rolling file appender in logback

My Goal with this is to create a simple JSON file that can either be directly viewed, and/or scraped with filebeat and sent to logstash for creating dashboards for operation performance.

-------------------- Configururation for  spring-boot-logger.log and spring-boot-logger.json  files {for log.debug("my log message},  Includes sleuth  ----------

```
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>

<springProperty scope="context" name="site" source="ci2.application"/>
<springProperty scope="context" name="app" source="spring.application.name"/>


<property name="LOGS" value="./logs" />


<!-- You can override this to have a custom pattern -->
<property name="CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN"
          value="%clr(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}){faint} %clr(${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p}) %clr(${PID:- }){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}"/>

<!-- Appender to log to console -->
<appender name="Console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <!-- Minimum logging level to be presented in the console logs-->
    </filter>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        <charset>utf8</charset>
    </encoder>
</appender>



<appender name="RollingFile"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOGS}/spring-boot-logger.log</file>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        <charset>utf8</charset>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- rollover daily and when the file reaches 10 MegaBytes -->
        <fileNamePattern>${LOGS}/archived/spring-boot-logger-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
        </fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>


<appender name="Json"
          class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOGS}/spring-boot-logger.json</file>
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
        <providers>
            <timestamp>
                <timeZone>UTC</timeZone>
            </timestamp>
            <pattern>
                <pattern>
                    {
                    "severity": "%level",
                    "service": "${app:-}",
                    "trace": "%X{X-B3-TraceId:-}",
                    "span": "%X{X-B3-SpanId:-}",
                    "parent": "%X{X-B3-ParentSpanId:-}",
                    "exportable": "%X{X-Span-Export:-}",
                    "pid": "${PID:-}",
                    "thread": "%thread",
                    "class": "%logger{40}",
                    "rest": "%message",
                    "schema":"ci2",
                    "group":"devops",
                    "site": "${site}"

                    }
                </pattern>
            </pattern>
        </providers>
    </encoder>  
    <rollingPolicy
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- rollover daily and when the file reaches 10 MegaBytes -->
        <fileNamePattern>${LOGS}/archived/spring-boot-logger-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.json
        </fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>

</appender>

<!-- LOG everything at INFO level -->
<root level="warn">
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
    <appender-ref ref="Console" />
    <appender-ref ref="Json" />
</root>

<!-- LOG everything at INFO level -->
<root name="org.springframework" level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
    <appender-ref ref="Console" />
    <appender-ref ref="Json" />
</root>


<!-- LOG "com.siemens.pl*" at INFO level -->
<logger name="com.siemens.pl" level="info" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
    <appender-ref ref="Console" />
    <appender-ref ref="Json" />
</logger>
```

-----------------  End logback config ---------------------------------

I am trying to add dynamicly adding values to the json log.

Something like

1)  Highest level support, add values from map as JSON entries in generated json

```
 something like



    Map myValues = new HashMap<String,String> ();
    myValues.put("startTime",startTime);
    myValues.put("endTime",endTime);
    myValues.put("op",operation);
    myValues.put("user",user);
    // ideal usage format, would add map as "key":"value"  to json output
    log.debug(myValues);
```

2) If appending a user generated sting to a logfile (with nothing added by logging), I could generate the log string (json myKeys + stander logging), and then append

```
    Map myValues = new HashMap<String,String> ();
    myValues.put("startTime",startTime);
    myValues.put("endTime",endTime);
    myValues.put("op",operation);
    myValues.put("user",user);

    #Generate JSON String that includes standard logging fields and dynamic
    # user fileds passed in myValues map
    String myLogStringToAppendToLogFile = generateLogString(myValues);


    #Ideal op would accept string and append user provide string to end of
    #logfile with no modification
    log.debug("RawString", myLogStringToAppendToLogFile );
    log.debug(myValues);
```

---

The above would be the most simple,  I am not sure if there is an API on a logger that would accept a map and add to log

Another option would for the logger add a fixed set of properties to the json file, and the the property value could be passed in on the user log line.

For example, from the logback def above
       -------------------

```
<appender name="Json"
          class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOGS}/spring-boot-logger.json</file>
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
        <providers>
            <timestamp>
                <timeZone>UTC</timeZone>
            </timestamp>
            <pattern>
                <pattern>
                    {
                    "severity": "%level",
                    "service": "${app:-}",
                    "trace": "%X{X-B3-TraceId:-}",
                    "span": "%X{X-B3-SpanId:-}",
                    "parent": "%X{X-B3-ParentSpanId:-}",
                    "exportable": "%X{X-Span-Export:-}",
                    "pid": "${PID:-}",
                    "thread": "%thread",
                    "class": "%logger{40}",
                    "rest": "%message",
                    "schema":"ci2",
                    "group":"devops",
                    "site": "${site}"

                    }
                </pattern>
            </pattern>
        </providers>
    </encoder>  
    <rollingPolicy
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- rollover daily and when the file reaches 10 MegaBytes -->
        <fileNamePattern>${LOGS}/archived/spring-boot-logger-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.json
        </fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>

</appender>
-----------------------

In this appender def, the <pattern> is used to add values to the json def for sleuth.    

How can I define entries in this pattern and pass in the dynamic value to the logger.  It looks possible and sleuth may do it with  

                     "trace": "%X{X-B3-TraceId:-}",
                    "span": "%X{X-B3-SpanId:-}",
                    "parent": "%X{X-B3-ParentSpanId:-}",
                    "exportable": "%X{X-Span-Export:-}",
```

Another API that would work is that the logger would accept a string and append the user provided string to the end of the log file

Answer (score 0):

All in all:
You don't need to create a logger, you need to check the appenders.
Furtunately, Logback already supports json serialization of Console Appender with a JSON Layout.

Configure the console appender in `logback.xml`/`logback-spring.xml`:

```
<appender name="json" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.contrib.json.classic.JsonLayout">
        <jsonFormatter
            class="ch.qos.logback.contrib.jackson.JacksonJsonFormatter">
            <prettyPrint>true</prettyPrint>
        </jsonFormatter>
        <timestampFormat>yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss.SSS</timestampFormat>
    </layout>
</appender>
```

And add a couple of dependencies in POM.

See [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-log-json-output) for a full tutorial

Comment: Is there a way, where I can just write my own JSONs, which doesn't have any of log related info, only the ones that I provide.

Answer (score 0):

```
<appender name="LOGSTASH" class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender">
                <destination>${logging.logstash.uri}</destination>
                <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
                    <customFields>
                        {"src": {
                        "component": "${logging.logstash.src.component}",
                        "platform": "${logging.logstash.src.platform}",
                        "app": "${logging.logstash.src.app}",
                        "log_type": "${logging.logstash.src.log_type}"
                        }}
            </customFields>
        </encoder>
</appender>
```

Comment: Thank you,  I should have been clearer.  my mistake.   I have a config like what you have for static value.   I wish to append a string to the end of a log file, no processing, just append the string.   That line is a json representation of dynamic info (op, startTime, endTime, requestId, user, + standard log fields) this line will be generated at log time.